# Why does the formation of iron in stars not produce any energy?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stars, binding-energy, elements, nucleosynthesis

Why does the formation of iron in  stars not produce any energy. I have a hunch that it might have something to do with the fact that iron has the highest binding energy per nucleon and hence (probably) is the most stable nucleus in the universe?

Comment: Actually the formation of iron which results from silicon fusion, does produce energy. However, fusion of iron itself would require additional energy. You may want to reword your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prof Rob has revisited this question, pointed out the errors in my original answer, and posted the correct answer below. Because my old answer was accepted, I cannot delete it and will try editing it instead with this note.
-NN

Comment: The answer is great, I would just add the binding energy curve itself, a nice plot is on [wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Binding_energy_curve_-_common_isotopes.svg). One can see that ${56}_{}Fe$ has the maximum binding energy per nucleon, as @niels nielsen pointed out.

Comment: I doubt that fusing Fe and He is particularly endothermic and I know that fusing $^{56}$Ni (the decay of which is what produces the Fe) and He is exothermic. It is the rearrangement of nucleons once they are *all* part of iron nuclei that requires energy, not the fusion reaction with iron (or its progenitor).

Comment: @profrob, how shall I edit? -NN

Comment: @profrob, will delete. -NN

Answer (score 1):

Producing iron is of course an energy-generating process and occurs in the brief silicon-burning phase at the end of a massive star's life.

Actually, adding alpha particles to iron-peak nuclei is also exothermic (e.g. the Q for adding an alpha particle to $^{56}$Fe is $+6.3$ MeV). It doesn't happen in the cores of massive stars for two reasons:

1. Once the core of a star is made of iron, then there aren't any alpha particles to fuse with. Fusion of two iron nuclei has a ludicrously high Coulomb barrier. So what you would have to do is break an alpha particle out of one iron nucleus and then fuse it with another iron nucleus. It is the *sum* of those two operations that is endothermic, because iron is near (not quite top, that is $^{62}$Ni) the peak of the binding energy per nucleon chart.
2. Even if you had the alpha particles, the temperatures required to initiate fusion with iron peak nuclei are hot enough to produce photons that can also photodisintegrate more massive nuclei. In some stars this photodisintegration process may precipitate a core collapse and a supernova.